# Solve $ (X+A)(X+A)'=\mathrm{diag}(I,0)+AA' $

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Let $A$ be a given $m \times n$ matrix with $m  \geq n$ and Rank$(A)=n$. Does there always exist  an $m \times n$ matrix $X$ (with Rank$(X)=n$) that solves,
$$
(X+A)(X+A)'=\left[\begin{array}{cc}I_{n} &  0_{n \times (m-n)} \\  0_{(m-n) \times n} &  0_{(m-n) \times (m-n)}\\ \end{array}\right]+AA'?
$$

Simplifying, I get 
$$
XA'+AX'+ XX'=\left[\begin{array}{cc}I_{n} &  0_{n \times (m-n)} \\  0_{(m-n) \times n} &  0_{(m-n) \times (m-n)}\\ \end{array}\right]
$$

but not sure where to go from here.

I was trying to investigate the case where $m=n$ but didn't make progress.

I suspect the answer is yes (but this is pure speculation from the case when all objects are scalars). This reminds me of Sylvester equations https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation and pseudo inverses https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse

Comment: If $m > n$, then the LHS has rank at most $n$, but I see no reason why the RHS should be rank $n$ (depending on the circumstances, I think it could very well be rank $m$). A counter-example would be given by $A' = (0,1)$. I don't have an opinion on the $n=m$ case, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y=X+A$; then $YY^T=diag(I_n,0_{m-n})+AA^T=B$.

Since $rank(YY^T)\leq n$, if we want that a solution exists, then necessarily $rank(B)\leq n$.

EDIT 1. Since $AA^T$ is symmetric $\geq 0$, $rank(B)\geq n$ and we assume that $rank(B)=n$. Since $rank(AA^T)=n$, the spd symmetric matrix $AA^T$ is in the form $diag(U_n,0_{m-n})$, where $U$ is a pd  symmetric matrix. Finally we may assume that $B=diag(b_1,\cdots,b_n,0_{m-n})$ where $b_i>0$. We can choose $Y=\begin{pmatrix}diag(\pm\sqrt{b_i})\\0_{m-n,n}\end{pmatrix}$.

EDIT 2. Answer to user. Necessarily, for any $y$, $[0_n,y^T]B[0_n,y]=0$; then $AA^T$ is in the form $\begin{pmatrix}U_n&V\\V^T&0_{m-n}\end{pmatrix}$. Thus if $A=[P,Q]^T$,then $QQ^T=0$, that implies that $Q=0$. Finally $V$ is also a zero matrix and we are done.

Conclusion. If $A$ is not in the form $[P,0]^T$, then $0$ solution; otherwise the solutions are $Y=[F,0]^T$ with $FF^T=I_n+PP^T=Wdiag(b_i)W^T$ where $W\in O(n)$. Thus there are at least $2^n$ solutions: $X=\begin{pmatrix}Wdiag(\pm\sqrt{b_i})W^T\\0_{m-n,n}\end{pmatrix}-A$.

Comment: What about @D.Thomine comment? with $A=(0,1)'$ in which case $YY'=diag(1,0)$ but $diag(1,0)+B=(1,0;1,0)$.... I think the issue is that $AA^T$ can also be $diag(0_{m-n},U_n)$. So maybe the statement holds as long as $AA^T=diag(U_n,0_{m-n})$?

Comment: @ user103828 , you are wrong; indeed the Thomine's example has no solutions (as he wanted) because $B=I_2$. See my second edit.

Comment: Ok. I see. Then, I don't quite understand your solution. Does your solution prove that there is always an $A$ that solves the equation?